# GAE Map Reduce - hitting entities more than once?

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

I'm using Map Reduce (http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) to do an operation over a set of entities.  However, I am finding my operations are being duplicated.

Are map reduce maps sometimes called more than once for a specific entity?  Is this the case even if they don't fail the initial time?

**edit**: here are some more details.

```
def reparent_request(entity):
    #check if the entity has a parent    
    if not is_valid_to_reparent(entity):
        return

    #copy it
    try:
        copy = clone_entity(Request, entity, parent=entity.user)
        copy.put() #we hard put here so we can use the reference later in this function.
    except:
        ...

    ... update some references to the copied object ...

    #delete the original       
    yield op.db.Delete(entity)
```

At the end, I am non-deterministically left with two entities, both with the new parent.

Answer (score 0):

I've reparented a load of entities before - it was a nightmare because of the exact problem you're facing.

What I would do instead is:

1. Create a new queue. Ensure its paused and that you have a lot of storage space dedicated to queues. It's only temporary, but you'll need it.
2. Instead of editing your entities in your map reduce job, add them to the queue with a name that will be unique for each entity. The key works fine.
3. When adding to the queue, because it's paused you'll get an error if you try and add the same named queue twice - so catch the error and skip it, because you know that entity must already have been touched by the map reduce job.
4. When you're confident that every entity has a matching queue task and the map reduce job has finished, unpause your queue. The queue will do the reparenting.

A couple of notes:
* the task queue size can get pretty big. Can't remember numbers, but it was gigs. Also the size of the queue doesn't update in real time - so don't worry that it might still says gigs of tasks when the queue is nearly empty. 
* the reliability of the queue storage is an unknown I believe. It didn't happen to us, but queue items could disappear I guess. Fortunately, you can rerun this process multiple times to ensure it worked, especially if you're deleting entities. 
* you may want to ensure you queue has a concurrency limit on it. Without one, a delay in the execution of a couple of tasks can absolutely cripple your application. Learnt that the hard way! I think 30 concurrent tasks went quite well for us.

Hope that's useful, let me know if you come up with any improvements!

Comment: That seems like an unnecessarily complicated solution.

Comment: Totally agree, but for what we're trying to achieve it was very effective. (we were doing more than just reparenting)

Answer (score 0):

App Engine mapreduce runs on the task queue, and like anything else that uses the task queue, tasks have to be idempotent - that is, running them multiple times should have the same effect as running them once. Tasks will occasionally be run more than once; the mapreduce library may have its own reasons for rerunning mapper tasks, too.

In your situation, I'd suggest creating the new entity with a key whose ID is the same as the old entity; that way running it multiple times will just overwrite the same entity.